# Modifying PATH with fish shell

Tags: shell, environment-variables, fish

I'm currently playing around with the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) and I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how the `PATH` variable is set. For what it's worth, I'm also using [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/tree/ecf1af6228b3d8ed7dde3304124645b2bc2980d3).

If I echo my current path I get:

```
➜ fish echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /opt/X11/bin /usr/texbin /Users/myname/.opam/system/bin
```

Looking at `~/.config/fish/config.fish` I see the following line

```
set PATH /usr/local/bin $PATH /Users/myname/.opam/system/bin
```

My question is (and this phrasing will probably reflect my lack of knowledge on the subject): prior to `config.fish` being processed, where is the `PATH` variable set? ie: where do all of the paths between `/usr/local/bin` and `/Users/myname/.opam/system/bin` come from?

Comment: the documentation describes the initialization files: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization

Comment: Ah. I tried finding the second file (```/etc/fish/config.fish```) and couldn't find it. I suspected it's because I installed fish with homebrew. I ran ```find / -name config.fish``` to find all the ```config.fish``` files on my system. The result was: 

```/Users/name/.config/fish/config.fish```,
```/Users/name/.oh-my-fish/templates/config.fish```,
```/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.1.0/etc/fish/config.fish```,
```/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.1.0/share/fish/config.fish```, and
```/usr/local/etc/fish/config.fish```.

I checked all of the results and none of them seemed to specify any PATH value.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

As stated in the [official fish tutorial](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#path), you can modify the `$fish_user_paths` universal variable.

Run the following once from the command-line:

```
set -U fish_user_paths /usr/local/bin $fish_user_paths
```

This will prepend `/usr/local/bin` permanently to your path, and will affect the current session and all future instances too because the -U argument will make the variable *universal*.

From the `fish` documentation:

> ... (Note: you should NOT add this line to `config.fish`. If you do, the variable will get longer each time you run fish!)
>
> fish_user_paths, a list of directories that are prepended to PATH. This can be a universal variable.

Comment: Do not add this to your fish_config file! It should be executed as a command.

Comment: `-U` is not required since `fish_user_paths` is already universal.

Comment: Since fish 3.x PATH will not grow, fish checks if any particular path from fish_user_paths exist in PATH and if not - prepends, if yes removes it and prepends.

Comment: So this "fish_user_paths" is an actual path or command? Or do I have to give my actual path like /folder1/folder2? @Phlogi

Comment: set -U fish_user_paths /opt/bin is the full command, while  fish_user_paths is a fish shell variable.

Comment: @kyb: The documentation says it can be a universal variable. To check, use set --show fish_user_paths

Comment: So much for the easier to use shell!  It doesn't make the shell game any less confusing. Hey,  at least you get a prettier prompt.

Comment: @Nishant If not in the config file, where else should it be added?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig, you can hard code it I guess. `PATH=$PATH:...` is never good in config files in general ... It keeps appending each time! Now sure what is the best way to do this in fish though. I am using bash mostly nowadays.

Comment: Please delete this answer or update it, it is no longer the preferred way to do this!

Comment: @ATL_DEV i use fish all the time and think it's a great shell, but I kinda agree with you there. Every time I'm about to set an environment variable I have to reach for the documentation. :| 
I suppose if fish was the industry standard like bash, we'd probably get better at it.

Answer (score 186):

**Current answer**

As of [fish 3.2.0](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/releases/tag/3.2.0), released in March 2021, the canonical approach is:

```
fish_add_path /opt/mycoolthing/bin
```

This works both one-off interactively, and in `config.fish` — it won't produce duplicates in the `config.fish` case.

---

**Previous answer for fish < 3.2.0**:

The recommended commands for modifying `PATH` from fish's [maintainers](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/527) are:

1. If you want to run the command once:

   ```
   set -Ua fish_user_paths /path
   ```
2. If you want to add a command to a startup script, this is idempotent:

   ```
    contains /path $fish_user_paths; or set -Ua fish_user_paths /path
   ```

Comment: @Maximilian Thanks! the second part of this answer definitely helped me fix slow start up in fish sessions. I had been using something more like the first command in my config.fish file. https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6136

Comment: whats the best way to remove a PATH variable? still `set -e fish_user_paths[index]`?

Answer (score 12):

Like all shells, fish inherits its PATH from the environment it is started in. How this is set for login shells differs between operating systems - on Linux, for example, `/etc/login.defs` controls the initial PATH set for all login shells. I don't know how this is set on OS X.

Next, like `bash` or `csh`, the initialisation files for the shell may alter the path. For fish on OS X, there is code in `share/fish/config.fish` to load paths from the standard OS X path configuration files `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*`. There is alternative code to set a useful path on Solaris.

There is also code to pick up paths from the universal variable `$fish_user_paths`, which is the [right way to  add something to your PATH and have it reflected across all shells](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_prompt).

Answer (score 6):

**1. Enumerate user paths:**

```
echo $fish_user_paths | tr " " "\n" | nl
```

**2. Append a new bin path, permanently:**

```
set -ga fish_user_paths my_appended_path
```

**3. Remove 7th bin search path by index: (see #1):**

```
set —eg fish_user_paths[7]
```

Comment: Tried this. Had to use `set --erase fish_user_paths[1]` to work. Missed a dash before erase and `-g` is apparently not an option in current version.

Comment: thanks - I've updated the 3rd instruction:  set -eg  works

Comment: `set -eg` didn't work for me (fish version 3.1.2), but `set --erase` did.

Answer (score 6):

The way that worked with me :

in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` add the following line:

`set -gx PATH /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2 $PATH`
This will append those directories to your $PATH Environment variable.

Comment: Also you can install export `omf install export ` .. this essentially bring back the bash-like export command

Comment: This will not add, but prepend the directories to the PATH. To append them, instead use `set -gx PATH $PATH /path/to/dir`

Answer (score 3):

In order to set variables for `shell config file`, I did as follows:

> The main command to set any user specific variable is
>
> `set -Ua fish_user_paths /path/to/bin/directory/`

`set -Ux fish_user_paths /usr/local/bin`
Run `touch ~/.config/fish/config.fish`, unless it exists.

1. `RUST`: `set -Ua fish_user_paths $HOME/.cargo/bin`
2. `JAVA`: `set -Ua fish_user_paths /path/to/java/bin`
3. `Node` & `nvm`: make sure you have installed `nvm` properly then

   `omf install nvm`

   `set -gx NVM_DIR /path/to/nvm`
4. `Go`: `set -Ua fish_user_paths /path/to/go/bin/`
5. `Scala`: `set -Ua fish_user_paths /path/to/scala/bin/`
6. `Groovy`: `set -Ua fish_user_paths /path/to/groovy/bin/`
7. `Maven`: `set -Ua fish_user_paths /path/to/mvn/bin/`
8. `Gradle`: `set -Ua fish_user_paths /path/to/groovy/bin/`

Finally, refresh your terminal.

PS in some operating system (eg OpenSuse), drop `a`.

[image: The result after configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions do not work well with python virtual environment. The path to virtual environment will not be the first one in the list.

In order to set path once and do not override it every time you start python virtual environment

You need to change the path conditionally in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, like this:

```
contains /home/$USER/.pyenv/bin $PATH; or set -x PATH "/home/$USER/.pyenv/bin" $PATH
contains /home/$USER/.local/bin $PATH; or set -x PATH "/home/$USER/.local/bin" $PAT
contains /home/$USER/.asdf/bin $PATH; or source ~/.asdf/asdf.fish
```

This will ensure that you have new paths in $PATH but wnen you spawn new shell for virtual environment you'll will not add these paths again.

Unfortunately paths set with `set -Ua fish_user_paths` would endup in the beginning of the $PATH, pushing your virtual environment path away from the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You may use a script like the one below to ease adding or removing paths:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish

#remove PHP72
for argv in /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin;
    while contains $argv $fish_user_paths
        set -l index (contains -i $argv $fish_user_paths)
        set –erase –universal fish_user_paths[$index]
    end
end

#add PHP74
for argv in /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin;
    if contains $argv $fish_user_paths
        echo "Path already contains $argv"
    else
fish_add_path $argv
    end
end

echo $fish_user_paths | tr " " "\n" | nl

brew services stop php@7.2
brew services start php@7.4
```

Copied from https://www.tai.ro/2021/10/22/how-to-switch-path-in-fish-shell-with-example-script/