# GOPATH environment variable not getting set in the Fish shell?

Tags: go, fish, gopath

I have a `~/.config/fish/config.fish` which contains the following lines:

```
set PATH $PATH (go env GOPATH)/bin
set -x GOPATH (go env GOPATH)
```

If I simply run `go env GOPATH` at the command line, I get the default location (`~/go`):

```
> go env GOPATH
/Users/kurt/go
```

However, the `$GOPATH` environment variable is not defined:

```
> echo $GOPATH
```

Why is the `$GOPATH` environment variable not getting set?

Comment: What about your path? It includes the $GOPATH/bin directory? Maybe you can't execute `(go env GOPATH)` in the config.fish file... In my config I have the full path: `set -x GOPATH /home/myuser/go`

Comment: Works for me (I use both fish and go) and have the same `set -x GOPATH (go env GOPATH)` in my *~/.config/fish/config.fish*. I suspect your actual situation is different from what you have reported here. One possibility is you haven't set `$PATH` appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

`set -x` will only affect your current session. Once you logout of that session, the export will go away.

`set --export --global` will export your environment across all running fish sessions, however is ephemeral and will not persist after you log out.

`set --export --universal` will export your environment across all running fish sessions, and is persistent.

```
-g or --global
       Causes the specified shell variable to be given a global scope. 
Global variables don't disappear and are available to all functions 
running in the same shell.  They can even be modified.

-U or --universal
       Causes  the  specified shell variable to be given a universal scope. 
If this option is supplied, the variable will be shared between all the current 
user's fish instances on the current computer, and will be preserved across 
restarts of the shell
```

If you are running a current version of fish, you can use the built in `fish_add_path (go env GOPATH)/bin` once and it's done, you don't have to have it in a conf file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34401308/336632 also see this solution.

Answer (score 1):

To add Go paths to your Fish shell, add the following lines to your config.fish:

```
set -x GOPATH $HOME/go
set -x PATH $PATH $GOPATH/bin
```